# How can a user's displayName be added to a Firestore database collection entry?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am setting up a simple webpage with Firebase Authentication and a Firestore database which takes user inputs from a form, adds the inputs as a collection document in Firestore, and then also outputs the whole collection. Each document in the collection has two fields, the Name and the Body of the document. The goal is to allow users to make posts on the website using the input form. Everything I described is working, but now I would like to display the `user.displayName` with the post, to show who exactly created the user input, and that's what I can't figure out how to do. Here's the relevant code, from the `script.js` of the website:

```
const createForm = document.querySelector('#create-form');
createForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  db.collection('forumposts').add({
    Body: createForm['body'].value,
    //the line below is what I cannot figure out how to set up
    Name: string(user.displayName) 
  }).then(() => {
    //reset the form
    createForm.reset();
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err.message)
  })
});
```

I'm still learning about JavaScript, so I apologize if I am missing something obvious. I know the user's displayName (which is collected upon sign up) is being collected properly, as I can log it to the console and it shows up correctly. I just cannot figure out how to then add it as a field in this database collection input. I have tried searching here on SO for related questions, but am only getting questions related to how the user can add a display name on sign-up. I already have the display name, I just need to input it into the database. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you setting the `displayName` during sign up? IT is not set automatically. Can you share the sign up code so we can confirm you are setting the name?

Comment: I'm using the Firebase Auth UI, which asks for the displayName at sign up, so yes, it is being set during sign up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where is the `"user"` defined? That could be null if no user is logged in so it's better to check for the user.

```js
const createForm = document.querySelector('#create-form');
createForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const user = firebase.auth().currentUser

  if (user) {
    db.collection('forumposts').add({
      Body: createForm['body'].value,
      Name: user.displayName || "No username"
    }).then(() => {
      //reset the form
      createForm.reset();
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err.message)
    })
  } else {
    console.log("NO user logged in")
  }
});
```

You don't need the `String()` constructor. If `displayName` is defined it'll be a string. You can use `if (user.displayName)` before adding the post to check if user has a display name.

Comment: This worked! Thank you, I realize I just had to add the const user bit, and it is now adding the name of the user to the post as desired.

Answer (score 0):

It's String(), not string(). As long as displayName is a property of user, it will be added to the database.